# Change color of Foundation drowpdown arrow in topbar

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

Been trying to change the dropdown arrow in the topbar of Foundation 6 but no luck with this [forum answer](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/675).

I do not see those classes in my Foundation 6, so what I did was:

```
.top-bar .is-dropdown-submenu-parent > a:after {
  border-color: #FF0000 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

But still has not change.

**HTML (ruby):**

```
<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">
        <%= image_tag('logo.png', size: '40x40') %>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Accounts</a>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
          <li><%= link_to 'Sales', sales_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Inventory', inventory_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Settings', settings_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Paste your html and css please

Answer (score 1):

**Please use this:-**

```
.top-bar .is-dropdown-submenu-parent > a:after {
  border-color: #FF0000 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you use scss, so you can configure foundation variables to change components view. [Here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/scss/settings/_settings.scss) is the list of all available variables. Change `$dropdownmenu-arrow-color` to set new color to arrow.

Answer (score 0):

It's due [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The "default" Foundaiton selector is

```
.dropdown.menu > li.is-dropdown-submenu-parent > a::after{}
```

Notice the first part of the selector, it uses two classes - `.dropdown` and `.menu` while your selector uses only `.top-bar`. And on the second part the `li` selector is also used. [Compare those two CSS selectors with this CSS specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

So, use that selector:

```
.dropdown.menu > li.is-dropdown-submenu-parent > a::after{
    border-color: #FF0000 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Or you can use `!important`.